# K-line sniffing problem

Tags: arduino, logic-analyzer

I'm facing a problem while trying to check the communication between two devices talking over k-line ISO 14230-4 KWP protocol.I have two master devices and one slave device (i'm calling them master because the slave doesn't communicate until the master initiate the communication) but I only connect one master to a slave and hook GND and K-line wires to salae logic analyzer.

On the first Master device i'm able to see the communication just fine the two devices keep communicating without an issue.

While on the second master device no communication is possible while the logic analyzer is hooked to K-LINE.the master keeps sending the init sequence but it doesn't get any response the K-line stays idle.

As soon as I remove the k-line wire from the logic analyzer the master gets the response and start the communication.

I don't know what is causing that I think the master device is designed as such when a logic analyzer is hooked the k-line wire stays high and can't be driven by the slave.

Tried two logic analyzers and an arduino (which also I was able to receive data from the first master and slave and was able to receive only the init sequence repeatedly without response with the second master device)

I want you to help me figure out why I can't logic analyze the second master device and what to do to prevent this from happening

Thank you

Comment: any differences in supply floating ground ?

Comment: any difference in line length?

Comment: There is no difference.the first master device and second one do the same job but from different companies. There is only a few upgrades on the second master.both devices get Ground and Power from the slave device.the line length is the same on both devices the pins are directly out from DB9 connector to a 0.5m cable.tried switching the cables between the two master devices but still the same problem